# Disable auto id generation in org-mode html export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I disable inclusion of `id`s when exporting file as html

Say for example, in the following file I have disabled `toc`

```
#+TITLE: Using org-mode
#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil html-style:nil html-scripts:nil

* Where to start
** Let’s begin here
```

Now if I export it with `M-x` `org-html-export-to-html`, I get the following output:

```
...
<div id="outline-container-org0c7ecf1" class="outline-2">
  <h2 id="org0c7ecf1"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> Where to start</h2>
  <div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">
  </div>
  <div id="outline-container-orga4a6d26" class="outline-3">
    <h3 id="orga4a6d26"><span class="section-number-3">1.1</span> Let’s begin here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I would like to not add the `id` attribute at all unless a `CUSTOM_ID` property is set or `toc` is enabled.

These randomly generated `id`s break when regenerated and thus make it less useful as an `id` that can be linked from some other source.

As a side note, this results in unnecessary noise in commits (that's the primary reason I'm trying to avoid this).

Comment: I have the same problem here, then I dive into the org source code, the id is generated by `org-export-new-reference` and returned by `org-export-get-reference`, the latter function gets called many places in `ox-html.el`, and unfortunately, there is no even an option to change the behavior, so, it's quite hard to achieve this, what a tragedy...

Comment: This is Emacs, you could just advise the function ( https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions ), or even redefine it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't *exactly* what you asked for, but it does solve:

> These randomly generated ids break when regenerated and thus make it
>   less useful as an id that can be linked from some other source.
>
> As a side note, this results in unnecessary noise in commits (that's
>   the primary reason I'm trying to avoid this).

I was having the same problems, so I came up with this: https://github.com/alphapapa/unpackaged.el#export-to-html-with-useful-anchors

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it seems there is no out-of-the-box solution to this problem. Here is a hacky solution that uses an output filter and a regex to remove the `id` attributes from the final HTML output:

```
(require 'ox-md)
(defun html-body-id-filter (output backend info)
  "Remove random ID attributes generated by Org."
  (when (eq backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     " id=\"[[:alpha:]-]*org[[:alnum:]]\\{7\\}\""
     ""
     output t)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions 'html-body-id-filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done out of the box, but there is a feature request for it at the Github repo: [Feature request: More "Vanilla" HTML](https://github.com/org2blog/org2blog/issues/252)

Comment: It sounds like the answer is that it can't be done yet, but that there is a request for such a feature. If so, you might want to say that directly.

Comment: The linked issue is for `org2blog` and *not* Org.  Has the issue been raised with the Org developers?